# log4j2 pass parameters to custom appender

Tags: java, log4j

Is is possible in log4j2 to define a parameter in the configuration file and get the parameter in the append() method of your custom appender?

For example, define a parameter like this in your properties file:

```
appender.myCustomAppender.param1 = Hello-World
```

Then in my appender do something like this:

```
public void append(LogEvent event) {
   org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReadOnlyStringMap map = event.getContextData(); 
       String param1 = map.get("param1");

...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 2):

We can create our own definition of Appender in XML according to documentation: [Log4j2 doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/extending.html#Appenders).

Every `@PluginAttribute()` corresponds to attribute in XML and every `@PluginElement()` corresponds to XML node.

Ex. java code:

```
@PluginFactory
public static StubAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") String name,
                                          @PluginAttribute("test") boolean test,
                                          @PluginElement("Layout") Layout layout){
    //do a thing
}
```

Will read properties from this XML:

```
<Stub name="STDOUT" test="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%date %level method: %class{1}.%method (%file:%line) - %message%n"/>
</Stub>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.  I pass my parameters via the properties section of the XML file:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="Param1">Hello-World</Property>
</Properties>
```

Then in my custom appender I do the following:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
String param1= configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().lookup("Param1");
```